# Sunset and blue light scattering

Tags: visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science

During Sunset we see the lower part of the sky changing into red colour wich is of course due atmospheric thickness increased... The higher parts of the sky are still blue suggesting that as blue light is rather scattered this colour should be formed due blue light coming from a thinner part of the atmosphere which could be only the upper part of the sky. Primarly atmospherically refracted blue light indirectly coming from the upper parts of the sky to us orthogonally to the Earth surface are not enogh scattered so it could eventually cause of the blue colour of that part of the sky... But for this to work there should be a phenomena caused by higher parts of the sky being eventually cloudy so in that particular case the sky should be entirely red... Is this making sense?...